# Maven properties at plugin execution time

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am trying to figure out how to set a maven property to a different value at different points in the lifecycle. For example, if I set a property at the project level

```
<project>
    <properties>
        <some.property>Value</some.property>
    </properties>
</project>
```

During a third-party plugins execution I would like to be able to change it to something else.

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.mcheely</groupId>
        <artifactId>requirejs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <executions>
           <execution>
                <!-- change the value here -->
           </execution>
           <execution>
                <!-- change the value here again-->
           </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Or alternatively, rather than go the variable setting route, It would work just as well if I could access a unique ID or property set inside the particular execution. For example-

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.mcheely</groupId>
        <artifactId>requirejs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <executions>
           <execution>
               <id>SomeID</id>
               <!-- change the value here -->
           </execution>
           <execution>
               <id>SomeID</id>
               <!-- change the value here again-->
           </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

and then access this variable like so

```
${execution.id}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you solve this? I have a similar problem

Comment: I also have this problem, did you solve this?

Comment: @HavenLin I didn't, I have moved on from Maven and Java so I don't remember if I ever found a solution

Comment: I could get some info with properties like ${plugin.id} but also couldn't access the execution id.

Answer (score 1):

Using profiles is an option (each profile will have it's requirejsplugin execution):

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>profile-1</id>
    <properties>
        <some.property>Value1</some.property>
    </properties>
    ...
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <id>profile-2</id>
    <properties>
        <some.property>Value2</some.property>
    </properties>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

The activate the desired profile with `-P` (but beware if you activate 2 or more)

Full doc [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).

Comment: Thanks for the info, seems like an option, but do the profiles execute in order with the -P or with the variables step on each other if I activate 2 or more?

Comment: I would say in order but you might want to verify that.